# SMTP, which one is the right answer?

Tags: php, email, smtp

"Originally invented as a Host-to-Host protocol, with SMTP Authentication, a User has to identify itself and after successful authentication, reception/transmission of his/her emails is granted."

= or ==

SMTP AUTH works exactly the same way as Outlook or any other Mail Client?

Comment: Do a [google] search for Telnet smtp. There are examples that you can use to stream with fsockopen.

Comment: CLARIFICATION: "SMTP Authentication" is a protocol.  "Outlook", "mail" are two client applications which implement that protocol.  Look here for more details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP_Authentication

Comment: thanks i won the argument :)

Comment: @jycr753 - "thanks i won the argument". Q: What was the argument?  Q: What did you decide was the answer?

Comment: @paulsm4 it was a argument with a friend saying that mail and out look did not work as SMTP authentication on php.. just geek talk ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly like that - you give a username, password and domain to send through. See a good example at http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebsmtp

Comment: i know this… but the concept of SMTP which one is the correct?